# Has the Hulk always been able to talk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, the-avengers, thor-ragnarok

In [*Thor: Ragnarok*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_Ragnarok) Hulk has taken full control, Banner states that usually, he feels like he's got a hand on the wheel but this time he had no awareness of what was happening. So Hulk did seem to become stronger mentally and take fuller control. This leads to Hulk talking.

Before that, we never saw Hulk talking, until [*Avengers: Endgame*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Endgame) Banner again tests with Gamma radiation and end up becoming Professor Hulk.

But in Endgame when the heroes traveled back in time to get the Infinity Stones, at the events of [*The Avengers* (2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(2012_film)), we see that Hulk from that time period talking. Which was never shown in the *The Avengers* (2012).

So is Hulk able to speak all the time and did he hide this from other Avengers?

Answer (score 61):

> But in Endgame when the heroes traveled back in time to get the Infinity Stones, at the events of The Avengers (2012 film), we see that Hulk from that time period talking. Which was never shown in the Avengers movie.

## Yes

It's established that the Hulk **can** talk coherently provided he's not in complete "rage" mode during, say, battle.

When he bashes Loki he clearly says:

> **Puny God**

Comment: Plus, as we learn in *Endgame*, he also said “So many stairs!” during the events of *The Avengers*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite OP is basically asking if Hulk being able to talk during that time period was retconned by Endgame, so that isn't a valid point.

Comment: @CaptainMan So what? It's still the same time period and so it's the same version of the hulk.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I didn’t spot that the OP mentioned that in their question.

Comment: @ToddSewell When OP says "But in *Endgame* when the heroes traveled back in time to get the Infinity Stones, at the events of *The Avengers (2012 film)*, we see that Hulk from that time period talking. Which was never shown in the Avengers movie." it is clear they are saying Hulk didn't talk in *The Avengers (2012 film)* (though they are remembering incorrectly as shown in this answer) but did talk in *Endgame* during the 'flashback'. OP is just confused if Hulk was always able to or if it was retconned.

Answer (score 45):

He spoke in the 2008 movie [The Incredible Hulk](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080)

> Leave me alone

[Source](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080/quotes?item=qt0388764)

Comment: It's listed in the official [The First 10 Years of MCU](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Marvel-Studios-First-Ten-Years/dp/1787730913) book, so that's official enough for me.

Comment: There's also a TVTrope for [HulkSpeak](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HulkSpeak) - whether this is "official" or not is debatable, but it does prove the general notion that Hulk has the power of speech.

Comment: @Jenayah Why does everyone seem to think this? No, The Incredible Hulk was *always* part of the MCU. There's an end credits scene with Tony Stark and everything. It's just as much a part of the MCU as every other MCU movie. (It's also pretty underrated, if you ask me. Certainly better than, say, Thor: The Dark World.)

Comment: @only_pro dunno. There's probably the thing about it not having had sequels. Other than that, mainly the fact that it didn't make much of an impression (agree, though; TDW was the meh-est MCU movie)

Comment: It doesn't have sequels because Universal still has rights to solo Hulk movies.

Comment: what @pboss3010 said. That is one of the reasons they bought Fox. To get X-men and FF back in the fold. Disney likes to share credit (and revenue) less than Sheldon Cooper.

Comment: He also says "Hulk SMASH!" during his battle with Abomination.

Comment: @aleppke I'm pretty sure that every on-screen iteration of the Hulk has been able to deliver an occasional "Hulk SMASH!", even going back to the old TV show.

Comment: @only_pro Wasn't that post-credit scene only added for the DVD release?

Comment: @Jenayah Possibly partly because they changed the actor from Edward Norton to Mark Ruffalo for the rest of the MCU films.  (While no *convincing* official reason has been given, it should be noted that Norton provided his own rewrites of the script for "The Incredible Hulk" on **every** day of filming)

Comment: @Izkata No. I saw it in theaters. I repeat: The Incredible Hulk has *always* been a full-fledged MCU film. Marvel has never stated otherwise and has always included it in their list. Because why wouldn't they? It's part of the MCU.

Comment: Building on what @pboss3010 said, it's not that Universal has the rights to produce solo Hulk movies but rather they have the rights to *distribute* them. Marvel *could* still make a lot of money from Hulk movies, but they wouldn't have any control over distribution, and at this point Universal would be unlikely to help them in any way. So any future Hulk film would likely tank due to Universal not playing nice in terms of distribution. But Marvel does fully own the movie rights to Hulk, which is why they can include in him in non-solo movies without worrying about Universal.

Comment: @Jenayah You must have missed GotG2, then.

Comment: @Chronocidal That's absolutely the reason most people don't think of it as "belonging" in the MCU. It's easy for movie buffs to forget that most people don't follow along with official statements of continuity - they just watch the movies. And different actors for the same character are one of the most obvious cues that it's a different universe - Toby Macguire is not Andrew Garfield is not Tom Holland, Ben Affleck is not Charlie Cox, and Edward Norton is not Mark Ruffalo.